# how do i load an external js file after the page has loaded AND use a function from that same js

Tags: javascript, html, external

I am trying to bring webcam.js file into a index.html file, but it needs to load after the page loads. Its a webcam file so it only turns on after the index file loads. I also have to be able to use a function from that file. 
So my external file is webcam.js, im using it in index.html, and I need to use the function showBlue() from webcam.js in the html file as well.

(bottom half of index.html)

```
<script src="C:/Users/Juniper/Documents/Apps/server/webcam.js" defer></script>
     <script>

     if (window.onload = showBlue) {
     window.onload = function loadDoc() {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", './screen.html', true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            window.location.href = 'screen.html';
        };
        xhttp.send();
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
```

currently, this doesnt change the screen to screen.html, BUT if i remove the if statement (if (window.onload = showBlue) { ) then screen.html will automatically load

Comment: It seems that you need a webpacker, like webpack or requirejs.

Comment: Do you control the source of the JS file that you are trying to load asynchronously?  If so, you can have the JS file tell you when it has loaded by calling a function you define.  If you don't control it, then the alternatives are a little more messy.

Comment: Additionally, `C:/Users/Juniper/Documents/Apps/server/webcam.js` will not load if you are trying to run this on a web server.  You need to use the web address, not the file system address.

Comment: What would the web address be? Like localhost:3000/blue.html

Comment: Yes, something along the lines of `http://localhost:3000/some/resource/file.js`.

Comment: if i run the file from Apps would it be http://localhost:3000/server/webcam.js

Answer (score 0):

You wrap it in an interval timer that periodically checks if the script has loaded.

```
var webcamInterval = setInterval( function() {
    if ( someWellKnownFunctionNameFromWebcamJs ) {
        clearInterval( webcamInterval );
        // Your code dependent on webcam.js here ...
    }
}, 100 );
```

Comment: the webcam.js has already been loaded into the index file first, so im still just checking that its undefined

Comment: Did you replace `someWellKnownFunctionNameFromWebcamJs ` with something from webcam.js? Are you sure that webcam.js is loading?  This will check every 100ms to see if it is no longer `undefined`.

Comment: yes i did all that, but if i bring an external js file into index.html doesnt it only load once?

Comment: "doesnt it only load once?" -- yes, that's why you call `clearInterval` when the resource is no longer undefined.

Comment: I use this all the time to load jQuery asynchronously, sorry its not working for you.  I suspect that your file is never loading like @zero298 pointed out above.  See this js fiddle for a functioning example: https://jsfiddle.net/q5ko6hxh/1/